# Iterating through an STL list

Tags: c++, list, iteration

For my Computer Science class, we are doing an assignment on depth first search and i need to access the adjacent vertices (which is contained in a list within a struct). I need to use reverse iteration to go through the list but my teacher clearly states in the specifications:

> "There are several ways to do this, and `for (it=x.end(); it!=x.begin(); it--)` is not one of them."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You use a reverse iterator

```
for(auto it=x.rbegin(); it != x.rend(); it++){...}
```

Use `crbegin()/crend()` if you want const iterators.

Comment: Ahh.. that makes sense. I forgot about reverse iterators as I've never used them before. Thanks!

Comment: @user3651021: Also, `std::reverse_iterator<normal_iterator>`